# Get an anchor text value among multiple anchor's with same href

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html is

```
<a id='_requestOne' href='#applynow'> apply one </a>

<a id='_requestTwo' href='#applynow'> apply two </a>

<a href='#applynow'> apply three </a>
```

I want to change the anchor text for the second one alone. so I implemented in script as

```
$("a[href='#applynow']").text("request call");
```

Its changing all the three tags, so I tried as

```
$("#_requestTwo a[href='#applynow']").text("request call");
```

But its not working. 
Can anyone give me a solution that how could I declare both id & href in same call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you get the element by the id alone? That is supposed to be unique. Then, after you have the anchor element, access the href attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is target the second Item of the jQuery Object:

```
$( $("a[href='#applynow']")[1] ).text('request call') //starts counting at 0
```

I do not advise on this, it makes the code less maintenable if the html markup changes. You have an ID, so use that instead.

```
$("#_requestTwo").text('request call')
```

PS:

The reason why your second try doesn't work is because you had an error in the selector:

```
$("#_requestTwo a[href='#applynow']") 
//should be 
$("a[href='#applynow']#_requestTwo")
```

Comment: Since one anchor from header another from several user control. So that I want to code with both id and href. the code suggest last is working fine. thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

First select anchors with href then specify with ID or select directly by ID because ID should be unique:

```js
$("a[href='#applynow']#_requestTwo").text("request call");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='_requestOne' href='#applynow'> apply one </a>

<a id='_requestTwo' href='#applynow'> apply two </a>

<a href='#applynow'> apply three </a>
```

---

Always select elements from low to high specificity like:

```
$("tagname.class");
```

Comment: The code given is working as expected. appreciated for the help & support. Thanks much